# Segmentation fault while building binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am building a *binary search tree*, but the function is giving segmentation fault. I don't know where is the problem.

The tree doesn't build the part in the `insertintree` does not work properly and I have tried ways but it is not working

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct node // structure of node
{
    int k;
    node* left = NULL;
    node* right = NULL;
};    
void insertintree(node* root, int key)
{
    if (root == NULL)//root addition
    {
        node* root = new node;
        root->k = key;
    }
    else 
    {
        if (root->k < key)  insertintree(root->right, key);
        else insertintree(root->left, key);
    }
}    
void inorder(node* root) 
{
    if (root != NULL) 
    {
        inorder(root->left);
        cout << root->k;
        inorder(root->right);
    }
}    
int main() 
{
    node* root = NULL;
    insertintree(root, 1);
    cout << root->k;
}
```

Comment: Did you use your debugger?

Comment: You need to pass by reference: `void insertintree(node*& root,int key)`

Comment: You redeclare `root`.

Comment: I feel like I saw this exact question the other day. Anyway, the problem is you're not passing by reference.

Comment: As @ThomasSablik said, use debugger to avoid "i don't know where is the problem" situation. This helps finding problem by yourself, as well as asking question on SO, if need arises.

Answer (score 3):

You have mainly two issues:

1. You need to pass the `root` by reference, otherwise, `insertintree`
   will work with a copy of the `root` you pass.

   ```
   void insertintree(node* &root, int key)
   //                     ^^^
   {

   }
   ```
2. secondly, in your first `if`'s body, you have re-declared a new `root`
   `Node` which will shadow the passed one. change to

   ```
   if (root == NULL)//root addition    
   {
        root = new node;
        root->k = key;
   }
   ```

Also avoid practicing with `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`: Why? See the following discusssiions:

- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)
- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: `insertintree will work with the copy of the root you pass` sounds like it is the same copy which is being passed. I think one should better say `insertintree makes a new copy of root you pass`. Or change `with the copy` to `with a copy`

Answer (score 2):

There's multiple problems with your code. The first is that you redeclare `root`.

```
void insertintree(node* root,int key) // root declared here
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        node* root = new node; // root redeclared here
```

These are two different variables (even though they have the same name). You should have written this

```
void insertintree(node* root, int key) // root declared once
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        root = new node; // now this is the root declared above
```

The second problem is that you are expecting the `intsertintree` function to change the root declared in `main` but it doesn't. Again just because two variables have the same name doesn't mean they are the same variable.

```
void insertintree(node* root,int key) // a variable called root
{
     ...
}

int main()
{
     node* root = NULL; // another variable called root
     ...
}
```

Changing the `root` variable in `insertintree` has no effect at all on the variable called `root` in `main`, they are different variables.

To make this work you have to *pass by reference*. When a variable is a reference then changes to it change the variable being refered to. Change your `insertintree` function like this

```
void insertintree(node*& root,int key)
                    // ^ this makes root a reference
{
```

Now `root` is a reference to the variable in `main` and changes to it will also change the variable in `main`.

And in the same way, when your recursively call `insertintree` like this

```
insertintree(root->right,key);
```

the `insertintree` function is going to be able to change `root->right` because it takes a *reference* to `root->right`.